# Get the shell being used within C

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am trying to get the shell that is being used (where the code is being executed on).

For example if the binary was named `tmp`

when I execute `./tmp` on a bash shell I get an printf of bash, but if I execute it on a zsh shell I get an printf of zsh

I currently tried

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char command[50];
    strcpy( command, "echo $0" );
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

But the only output I get is `sh` which is not my desired output.

Comment: The `system` command executes the given command using `/bin/sh`, so `$0` will always be `sh`. See [the man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) for additional details.

Comment: I see so the `system` command only executes the code with the `/bin/sh`, do you have any idea of any other commands that might allow me to do what I desire. Additionally I have looked at `execl` command but to execute the command I would need to know the shell I am currently using which is what I desire.

Comment: Note that looking at `SHELL` isn't going to answer the question, "what is the parent of the current command"; if I am using `bash` and I start a `dash` shell and then run your code, your code will report `bash` even though it was actually launched from `dash`.

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in the title.  Instead, click the checkmark to accept the answer that has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to answer the question, "what is the parent of the current command", you'll need to:

1. Get the process id of the parent process, and then
2. Figure out the command name for that pid

But if you are trying to answer the question, "what shell is configured as the default shell for the current user", that is a different question. I'm assuming you're asking the first question here.

---

Getting your parent PID is easy; just use the `getppid()` function:

```
pid_t parent_pid;
parent_pid = getppid();
```

Getting the command associated with that pid is straightforward but requires a few more steps. The simplest solution is probably reading the value from `/proc/<pid>/comm`, which means:

- Compute a pathname from the `parent_pid` variable
- Open the file
- Read the contents into a buffer

Maybe something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#ifndef BUFSIZ
#define BUFSIZ 8192
#endif

int main()
{
    char path[BUFSIZ], comm[BUFSIZ];
    pid_t parent_pid = getppid();
    int fd;

    // compute the pathname
    if (snprintf(path, BUFSIZ, "/proc/%d/comm", parent_pid) > BUFSIZ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "path too long\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // open the file
    if (-1 == (fd = open(path, O_RDONLY))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open comm file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // read the contents into the `comm` variable
    memset(comm, 0, BUFSIZ);
    if (-1 == read(fd, comm, BUFSIZ-1)) {
        perror("read");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("launched from: %s\n", comm);

    if (-1 == close(fd)) {
        perror("close");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Launched from a `bash` shell, we see:

```
bash$ ./getparent
bash
```

Launched from `tclsh` we see:

```
bash$ tclsh
% ./getparent
launched from: tclsh
```

Or from Python:

```
bash$ python
>>> print(subprocess.check_output('./getparent').decode())
launched from: python
```

So it seems to work as advertised.